# How to add a report on the account page using Visualforce

Tags: community

I have created a report and would like to add it the account page using visualforce page.

Is there a way to create it ?.

Comment: Why not just add the report directly onto the account layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display report in the Visualforce just by using `iframe`. You need to use the report id.

Check this:

```
<apex:page >
  <apex:iframe src="SomeReportId">
</apex:page>
```

Also check this:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_embed_pagelayout.htm&language=en_US